# Configuring Spring Security with DB2 Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, spring-security, db2, spring-roo

I am following this template http://kh-yiu.blogspot.com/2012/12/spring-mvc-security-custom.html but I have run into an issue.  The stored procedure that I need to call requires that I call it with the username & password and the loadUserByUsername(String username) doesn't give me access to the password.  Can someone please assist on this?  I am happy to provide more code if that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a trusted context. You establish the connexion to the database with a generic user, and then you swith the user via a trusted context.

You should give public execution to the stored procedure that you want to call to invoke the user, and then, you establish the trusted context.

For more information about this

- Complete Java DB2 example http://hoteljavaopensource.blogspot.fr/2011/05/trusted-context-db2-spring.html
- Trusted context in InfoCenter http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0050515.html